# How to click on element with selenium in python on this page?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, automation, bots

[image: 1]

https://iphone.facebook.com/marketplace/selling/item/

base on image that i've upload,
i have to fill some column and click few button to post product.
i still try to create selenium bot automation to do it but i have problem on clicking the button element like, post button, category (not button but i have to click it to show its option) and last one is location (not button to but have to click it to show the column).

i have csv file as source of data, and i write code below to fill data ;

```
        scraper.element_send_keys('input[name="title"]', data['Title'])
    scraper.element_send_keys('input[name="price"]', data['Price'])
    scraper.element_send_keys('textarea[name="description"]', data['Description'])
```

what i need now is click on post button and fill the location and category with data from csv file.

sorry for my bad english but i need help.

Thank you.

I have try using xpath, id and name tag to locate the element for click but not work.

i want code that can click on button and column that i mention above.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you should use .keys to click on the post button, and using the id is a good idea.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver.impicitly_wait(4) 
post_button = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'u_0_25_2e')
post_button.send_keys(Keys.'RETURN')

or 
post_button = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'u_0_27_ty')
post_button.send_keys(Keys.'RETURN')
```

you can open try, except block or use driver.wait until expected conditions.

Hope it helps.

Comment: can you help me with location and category column ?